# Laravel 8 Can't Trigger Modal and Dropdown

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

So I want to use bootstrap modal in my project, I followed the official bootstrap documentation about modal, to test it out I just simply copy and paste the code to my blade. and somehow after I press the button the modal is not showing up. I pretty much sure followed the documentation. 
and I realized that this also happens to the dropdown function
can anyone help me with this?

Modal

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, ALWAYS add your code to the question. Based on my experiences, check the file/libraries that needed. In the head of the html there should be bootstrap.css. Then JS files: first jquery,  after that bootstrap.js

Comment: sorry for not including the code before, since I only did copy and paste and do nothing with it so I thought not Including the code might be fine. sorry man

Comment: Is the javascript definitely included in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shout out to [Rouhollah Mazarei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5876267/rouhollah-mazarei) and [Rwd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033654/rwd) after reading their comment, I did some recheck on the code and found out that the js and css include code is missing. It still works on my other blade so I thought it already included. thanks